# What is the best way to target users for which "Hometown " is different to "Location" on Facebook?

Tags: facebook-ads-api

Facebook doesn't allow you to target hometown, only location. 
https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151621858082186

However, there must be a clever strategy to get around this. What are people doing to target users that live in other cities to the one they grew up in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the ability to target people who are away from home and also by their location. So you could target people who live in London and who are away from home.

This will not let you target people who are from a specific city however.

[image]